# How to get keycode for hash #?

Tags: javascript

May I know what is the keycode for hash sign (#)? I have searched through some resources but couldn't find. Is it possible to get keycode for this symbol? How about other punctuations? Thanks.

Comment: [link](http://expandinghead.net/keycode.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find out the keycodes for whatever letter by simply running this code (try it now in your console):

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) { console.log(e.which); };
```

Then just type the letter you're interested in, and it will show up in the console.

`#` is `35`, btw.

Comment: KEYCODE Name is KEYCODE_POUND

Answer (score 3):

It will be its ASCII value which is 35.

Full table can be found [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

<strike>However, assuming user is typing it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> then you'll need to catch the key code of the digit 3 (which is 51) plus check the `shiftKey` property of the `event` object: when true and the key code is 51 it means `#` was typed.</strike>
(The above is correct only for specific keyboard layout, sorry)

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/GPG6L/1/) using `onkeypress` to detect the key stroke.

Comment: That last part is not true. On the german keyboard layout, `#` is its own key which requires no modifier, yet it will still return keycode 35

Comment: the linked JSFiddle has the real answer: `(event.keyCode || event.which) === 35` actually gets you the hash recognition event. If you try to capture the `shift`+`3` event you will find that `e.target.value` doesn't yet contain the `#` char

Answer (score 1):

Some reason 35 wasnt working for me.  The # keyCode is `51` worked for me